# Can't test for Null hashtable value in C# program

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, hashtable

I have a Hashtable called EmployeeInformation in my ASP.Net 4.0 web page (written in C#) and I want to check if a particular item ("DateEff") in the Hashtable has a null value. When I walk through the code with the debugger, I see that EmployeeInformation["DateEff"] has a value of {Null}. However, when I get to this condition:

```
if (EmployeeInformation["Context"].ToString() != "Existing" && EmployeeInformation["DateEff"] != null && EmployeeInformation["DateEff"].ToString() != "")
     <do something here>
```

my code sees that all three conditions are true and continues on to the "do something here" line of code. I've tried using

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmployeeInformation["DateEff"])
```

also, but the result is the same. I have also checked that EmployeeInformation contains the key DateEff and it does. Does anyone know why this is happening?

---

Based on MethodMan's comment below, I went back to see how I was populating the Hashtable. Here's what I'm doing:

```
string strDateHired = txtDateHired.Text;
            if (strDateHired == string.Empty)
                dtDateHired = SqlDateTime.Null;
            else
                dtDateHired = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateHired);
            EmployeeInformation.Add("DateEff", dtDateHired);
```

So the problem is that my value isn't null, it's SqlDateTime.Null. But how do I test for that? I can't convert EmployeeInformation["DateEff"] to a DateTime because it's empty.

Comment: is the value `null || Null` there is a difference can you show more code for example how are you populating the HashTable..? also can you change the code to check if `Contains || ContainsKey` function

Comment: note that Dates are simple types. if your 'DateEff' isn't a nullable date, it will never be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (based on your clarification)  `Convert.IsDBNull(DateEff)` will be true. You are setting that value to DBNull, not null as defined by c#.

Fun, right!?

Comment: That's it! Thank you bri! And yes, I'm having a great time. ;)

Comment: Also, just a suggestion, you may want to modify your answer to show that it's really Convert.IsDBNull().

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for a bogus field that you know is never populated, does `<do something here>` ever run? If so, I would question if DataEff is getting populated when you aren't expecting it to be.